# Hangfire Background job creation failed with InvalidCastException

Tags: asp.net-core, hangfire

I am trying to add hangfire in my .net core project.It creates Hangfire database but throws an exception whenever I try to add a recurring or background job

> > Hangfire.BackgroundJobClientException: Background job creation failed. See inner exception for details.
> > ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' to type 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.

Here is my code

```
services.AddHangfire(config =>
        config.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseDefaultTypeSerializer()
        .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Hangfire"),
        new Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorageOptions
        {
            SchemaName = "Test"
        }));
        services.AddHangfireServer();

        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        backgroundJobClient.Enqueue(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello Hanfire job!"));
```

I thought there might be some issue with the version of Hangfire packages I am using so I also tried previous versions but it did not make any difference.
One suggestion which I have found is to replace System.Data.SqlClient library with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient but it is not possible because Hangfire.SqlServer requires System.Data.SqlClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue by using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead of System.Data.SqlClient like this

```
.UseSqlServerStorage(() => new Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Hangfire"))
```